# WCF Namespaces Best Practice

Tags: .net, wcf, namespaces

I'm trying to obtain this result:

In WCF Project, to have multiple servicecontract interfaces (separated by entities like `Product`, `Order`, etc)

But, in Web Project, I want to have an single service client instance, and i want to call my methods something like that:

`myServiceClient.Products.GetFirst();` or
`myServiceClient.Orders.GetAllByStatus(5)`

How do I achieve this? I tried a few things, but all of them were far from what I wanted.

Comment: I don't think you can - it's one contract per service.  ABC - Address, Binding, Contract.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a completely different approach/architecture instead. Take a look for instance, at [this article](http://bit.ly/RrJRvD).